# Python: Pillow not rendering Khmer language properly

Tags: python, fonts, python-imaging-library

I am using Pillow to generate an image with QR code and text in both Khmer and English.
The QR code and English text are showing properly, but Khmer text is not displayed correctly in KhmerOScontent font.
[Output Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k4870.png)

These are the lines for the 2 places where Khmer text is shown:

```
MyfontName = ImageFont.truetype('fonts/KhmerOS_content.ttf', 10)
 
draw.text((w/2,110),wrap_name,font = MyfontName,fill=(0,0,0),anchor =
"mm",align="center")

draw.multiline_text((w/2,290),wrap_address.center(60),font =
MyfontName,anchor = "mm",fill=(0,0,0),align="center")
```

I am wondering whether this issue arises because Pillow is not compatible with Khmer Font. Could anyone please help me investigate the issue or give me any suggestion?